# Dealing with additional "+AC0" in my data

Tags: rstudio

I'd like to ask if there is an option to change part of dataframe in columns. I need to operate on CSV file that was saved in UTF-7 which causes adding `"+AC0"` in front of every minus value like:

```
+AC0-0.9949341
```

I need to get rid of this. I already tried

```
data1$x <- as.character(data1$x) > data1$x[data1$x == "+AC0"] <- ""
```

and

```
data1[data1[["x"]] == "+AC0","x"] <- ""[screenshot][1]
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell it's UTF-7 data. So you should be able to force UTF-7 text encoding when reading the file and have it all automagically go away.