# Could any one help me why am I getting +AC0 in the dataframe when I imported the csv file

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

I have include the snap here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy892.png)

Comment: Perhaps utf-7 format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482702/dealing-with-additional-ac0-in-my-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an encoding format error. Generally pandas defaults to utf-8 character encoding while reading files. You can experiment with other character encodings to avoid `+AC0`.

Try using `pd.read_csv(<file_path>,encoding="utf16)`

If above doesn't work try with other standards. You can refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings